# SSRS Check Boxes

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a customer demand to create a check box as a parameter . when the checkbox is selected the data should show the value for that checkbox otherwise all data should be shown

For example if the table has a column where if a student is active then value is 1 in the column and inactive has 0. Now there will be a check box and if the check box is selected then the value for 1 will be shown in the table else all the values.

What approach can i follow
thanks in advance

Comment: Which SSRS version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: For example if the table has a column where if a student is active then value is 1 in the column and inactive has 0. Now there will be a check box and if the check box is selected then the value for 1 will be shown in the table else all the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter of type BOOLEAN (TRUE or FALSE). If you label it as "Show active students?" then the TRUE/FALSE options make more sense to them.

Then on your filter you can use something like ..

```
=Fields!StudentActive.Value = iif(Parameters!ActiveStudents.Value = TRUE, 1, 0)
```

Depending on where you filter, of course. You can always pass that direct to the SQL in the dataset by using (pseudocode):

```
where Active = (@StudentActive)
```

and on the dataset, you can pass the value as
[image: Parameters on dataset]

Alternatively, you can create a list parameter:
Create the parameter like this:
[image: Parameter Creation]
and set the values using Available Values on the parameter:
[image]
Similar pseudocode applies for filtering in SQL:

```
where Active in (@StudentStatus)
```

This will allow multiple selections of status.

Comment: Thank you BishNaboB, for sharing the answer. is it possible to have it as check boxes --- just asking. customers requirement